# Access Identities within Configuration Profiles

Tags: iphone, client-certificates

I'm developing an application  for a company that requiers their users to identify themselves using a  certificate.

Basically the application will create a connection  with the server and, using the NSURLConnnection delegate methods, the  app will send the user credentials. Right now I have been able to read  the credentials from a certificate deployed as a resource in the  application bundle and send the credential to the server. We have also  been able to perform an OTA enrollment, and I need to know if it is  possible to deploy a personal certificate via OTA enrollment process and  then access that certificate with the application we are developing.

I  have read documentation stating that applications have access only to  its own keychain items, but I don't know if it is possible to specify  somehow the application ID in the Configuration Profile (in a similar  way that it is done to share a keychain between applications) and then  have access to those certificates. Or perhaps it is a different way to  achieve the task of delivering personal certificates that are accessible  using our application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you sovled this problem  ?

Comment: Sorry, I've been absent. In short. You cant